# Model's Child Collection is Always Null

Tags: asp.net-mvc-4

I can't seem to understand child collections in ASP.MVC 4 and Code First binding.  I always get an error that the model object is null when it comes to child collections.  I can't even add a check for if the child collection is null because the model is null.

I have verified that in the controller if I create a Batch object and add steps to it, then it will work.

I'm sure this is something simple, but I can't figure it out.

Here are my objects:

```
public class Batch
{
    public virtual int Id { get; set; }
    public virtual string Title { get; set; }
    public virtual string Details { get; set; }
    public virtual ICollection<Step> Steps { get; set; }
}
public class Step
{
    public virtual int Id { get; set; }
    public virtual string Title { get; set; }
    public virtual int Days { get; set; }
    public virtual Batch Batch { get; set; }
}
```

Here is my controller action:

```
    [Authorize]
    public ActionResult Create()
    {
        return View();
    }
```

Here is my view:

```
@model BC.Models.Batch

@{
    ViewBag.Title = "Create";
}

<h2>Create</h2>

@using (Html.BeginForm())
{
    @Html.ValidationSummary(true)

    <fieldset>
        <legend>Batch</legend>

        <div class="editor-label">
            @Html.LabelFor(model => model.Title)
        </div>
        <div class="editor-field">
            @Html.EditorFor(model => model.Title)
            @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.Title)
        </div>

        <div class="editor-label">
            @Html.LabelFor(model => model.Details)
        </div>
        <div class="editor-field">
            @Html.TextAreaFor(model => model.Details)
            @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.Details)
        </div>

        <div>
            <h3>Steps</h3>
            // Here is where I get a error that model is null
            @if(model.Steps != null)
            {
                foreach(var item in model.Steps)
                {
                    @Html.EditorFor(model => item)
                }
            }
        </div>
        <p>
            <input type="submit" value="Create" />
        </p>
    </fieldset>
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Instantiate your model and pass it to the view.

```
public ActionResult Create()
        {
            var model = new Batch();
            return View(model);
        }
```

That will solve the NullReference exception on the null model in the view.

However, when you reach the Psot action, Steps (the collection within Batch) will likely be null.  To solve this, new up the collection in the constructor like so:

```
public class Batch
    {
        public Batch()
        {
            Steps = new Collection<Step>();
        }
        public virtual int Id { get; set; }
        public virtual string Title { get; set; }
        public virtual string Details { get; set; }
        public virtual ICollection<Step> Steps { get; set; }
    }
```

Comment: I did exactly what you wrote in the Create action, and it throws the same compilier error.  Compiler Error Message: CS0103: The name 'model' does not exist in the current context

Comment: Ok, in my view, I change lower case model to upper case Model and it worked with the change in the controller action of passing in a new batch.  The second part of your response, the setting of the collection in the constructor doesn't work.  I get the following error: The property 'Steps' on type 'Batch_E85AD838AF575CFACF76B82A41844C5D89E88CB62530C4C26D5F390441401D29' cannot be set because the collection is already set to an EntityCollection.

Comment: @Brian That's an entity framework error that is probably happening in your repository/context, no?  It suggests a problem with the change tracking proxy created when using the 'virtual' keyword on a property.  Another issue entirely.

Comment: Thanks.  Your right, it was that I had marked the Id field as Virtual and the Entity Framework doesn't like that.  Once I took virtual off the Id field, everything you posted worked like a charm.  Thank you very much for the help!

Comment: Just to be clear, here were my exact steps to change my original code.  I took off virtual from the Id field.  I passed the view an instance of the Batch to work with.  I changed the @if(model.Steps != null) and foreach(var item in model.Steps) lines in the view to use upper case Model instead of lower case model.  I still don't understand why that was needed though.

Comment: @Brian `Model` is a property of the System.Web.Mvc.ViewDataDictionary object.  It's the property you use to access your view model in the view. `model`, as in `@Html.EditorFor(model => model.Title)`, is an arbitrary variable in the lambda expression and could be replaced with `m` or `x` or whatever.

Comment: Duh, I wasn't even thinking that way, but it makes total sense now that you explained it.  Huge thanks for the help.